# The code is correct, but an img file stored locally is not displayed - React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

> On this project, I'm using the MUI library

I have an image on this route `/assets/images/banner.png` (I've already verified the route and the name of the image is the correct one) The code should be correctly showing me the **"banner.png"** but it isn't

**This is my component HeroBanner.js**

```js
import React from 'react';
import { Box, Stack, Typography, Button} from '@mui/material';

import HeroBannerImage from '../assets/images/banner.png';

function HeroBanner() {
  return (
    <Box sx={{
      mt: { lg:'212', xs:'70px' },
      ml: { sm: '50px' }
    }} position='relative' p='20px'>
      <Typography color='#FF2625' fontWeight='600' fontSize='26px'>
        Fitness Club
      </Typography>
      <Typography fontWeight={700}
      sx={{ fontSize: { lg: '44px', xs:'40px'}}}>
        Sweat, Smile <br /> and Repeat
      </Typography>
      <Typography fontSize='22px' lineHeight='35px' mb={3}>
        Check out the most effective exercises
      </Typography>
      <Button variant='contained' color='error' href='#exercises'>Explore Exercise</Button>
      <img src={HeroBannerImage} alt="hero-banner" className="hero-banner-img" />
    </Box>
  )
}

export default HeroBanner
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code, and it worked for me. Maybe try importing another image or something. Make sure to check the folder names and image name.

This is the link for the tested code : [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/strange-gates-9zoo4n?file=/src/components/HeroBanner.js)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).